# Wrapping my head around client components with dynamic data

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I get caught up in client/server data fetching issues a lot and am struggling to understand the accepted ceremony around rendering dynamic data in client components in react (specifically next 14).

I understand that fetching data is recommended to be a server sided operation to save from credentials being exposed (unless you are using api endpoints).

Take this example; I fetch the data in my server component or page, lets say for example its user comments. I pass that to my client component that renders the previous comments along with a form to add new comments. The form can use a server action to add another comment to the list of previous comments with useState or useOptimistic (hence why its a client component, also server actions recommended for forms)

Fine so far, but what about if I want to render other dynamic data within that comment component? What if say, I wanted to render avatars for each previous comment and new comments submitted via the form? Usually that would require another data fetch of the users table using the commenter id.

So, without restructuring the original logging of data and saving all this extra user info in the comments table (which feels like a lot of data duplication), what's the generally accepted way of going about this?

Or as another example, a user mentioning @ feature that could query the list of currently subscribed users using ids from the comments section and return suggestions within the comment form? What is the generally accepted best practice here? Would you use another server action? Structure your data so you already have access to data like that from the original call? Or is this in fact a good use case for an API route?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Your "question" is actually many unfocused questions, some of which are soliciting opinions.  Please review the guidelines and rules for asking questions (one, focused definitively answerable question that does not rely on opinions) as well as take some time to understand this purpose of this site.  It is not a free-form help or discussion forum.